# Foraging/wild food - on topic? Should we/do we have a tag?

Tags: discussion

It appears that there's no tag for foraging or food (fruit/veg/fungi) from the wild.  Likely questions would appear to be on topic, analagous to [[ingredient-selection]](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/ingredient-selection/info) for bought ingredients.

While it's on-topic (and [in use](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/search?q=foraging)) at outdoors.se, many culinary aspects would probably find a better audience here.

So I think we should have a tag and accept questions.  I have a question in mind to start things off unless someone can point out a good or policy reason why we shouldn't.

Comment: I think the broad outlines of scope here are fairly well established by https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/discussion-should-plant-identification-questions-be-acceptable-here (and even earlier, https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/questions-about-foraging) - essentially, "is this edible" and other identification questions are off-topic, but questions about cooking with a given foraged ingredient are on-topic. Could you clarify whether you're trying to refine or change that scope?

Comment: @Cascabel the earlier question is closer, though I reckon this isn't a direct duplicate, and it suggests that I'm in scope: My Q, which I'll ask when I've had time to formulate it properly, is based on already having a positive identification of something known edible with suitable preparation (acorns, which need soaking to get the tannins out before roasting), but I haven't been much on selecting/harvesting at the right stage of ripeness.

Comment: @Cascabel I've asked the question, and had a go at a [tag wiki](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/foraging/info).  That could do with another pair of eyes.   I think "wild" or "wild-food" would be good synonyms.

Comment: @ChrisH tag wiki looks good to me. Thanks for also clarifying what’s _not_ contained.