# Should place-setting questions be closed?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are questions about food presentation and table setting on- or off- topic?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/820/are-questions-about-food-presentation-and-table-setting-on-or-off-topic)

This question refers to [Tine's Arrow with regard to forks](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/9943/41) which was just asked on Seasoned Advice.

I knew I'd seen a similar question before but couldn't place it; finally I remembered that it was part of our [Area 51 definition](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1288/food-and-cooking/1584#1584) phase, as one of the highest-voted off-topic examples.

But, that was before the whole [serving](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/190/41) hubbub here that arose as a result of discussions on whether or not questions on subjects like presentation and beverage pairing were on topic (we decided that they were).  Table-setting was listed as a "meh" topic - no strong feelings one way or the other.

Well, it's come up, so time to decide: Is it on topic?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has come up on meta a few times before:

[Are questions about food presentation and table setting on- or off- topic?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/820/are-questions-about-food-presentation-and-table-setting-on-or-off-topic)

[Are we about serving, or just cooking/food preparation?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/are-we-about-serving-or-just-cooking-food-preparation)

Place settings are not food, and are not really involved in the preparation of food. This seems clearly off-topic to me.

Comment: Good sleuthing; and shame on me for missing such an obvious duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I like the idea of "food experience" and the question seems okay by me. I could see having a policy where you carefully weed out all but extremely non-duplicate questions, and only as part of a larger scene of culinary couture. Random questions about how you should do placesettings at home would be silly. But, in the professional context, I liked the tone of this question.